# Using RegEx on CSV File before HTTP Request - JMeter

Tags: regex, csv, jmeter

Is it possible to first load CSV, then use RegEx on it and use that data extracted for HTTP Request? At this moment I have RegEx's prepared, but it doesn't seems to work. When I use reference to them in HTTP Request it doesn't see this variable. It looks like my RegEx ain't used before HTTP Request.
My RegEx is prepared with settings checked:

- Apply to: JMeter Variable
- Field to check: Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expression Extractor is a **[PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)**, it means that it is executed **after** the request. If you need to apply the regular expression to a JMeter Variable in the time of the request I would suggest to consider [__regexFunction()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__regexFunction) instead.

JMeter Functions can be placed anywhere in the script and they are evaluated directly when they are called so it seems it is something you're looking for.

For extended information on JMeter Functions check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series

Comment: I've created _regexFunction() and it returns me nothing. I've tested my regular expression here: http://regexr.com/ and also I've checked if JMeter variable, that I'm passing to function, has anything in itself. I've put it in HTTP Request -> Path. Is this proper place for it?

Comment: For sure function is called and done, but it can't find any match. Even when I use [^*] as RegEx (which should match everything) I'm still receiving empty output. This is my function: ${__regexFunction([^*],$0$,1,,NULL,,${regex})} - where ${regex} is my JMeter Variable

Comment: Try this one: `${__regexFunction((.*),$1$,1,,,,regex)}`

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with variable passed to function. When I've passed it with ${regex} he received nothing, but when I did it like you said (only regex) result was fine